# Ansible Error reading config file: File contains no section headers

Tags: ansible

#### SUMMARY

**As per documentation for [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings), we can place `ansible.cfg` in current directory of the project we are working on and Ansible will search for a config file in the order specified in link above.**

However, it appears that ansible is unable to correctly parse `ansible.cfg` file within my project directory.  I am not sure but I think it has to be with the Ini ConfigParser

###### ANSIBLE VERSION

```
  ansible 2.6.3
  config file = /Users/pnotes/Code/Terraform/Blog/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/pnotes/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/pnotes/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/pnotes/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.4 (default, Feb 26 2018, 21:07:35) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]
```

#### CONFIGURATION

output of "ansible-config dump --only-changed"

```
Error reading config file (/Users/pnotes/Code/Terraform/Blog/terraform/ansible.cfg): File contains no section headers.
file: '/Users/pnotes/Code/Terraform/Blog/terraform/ansible.cfg', line: 3
'vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt\n'
```

#### OS / ENVIRONMENT

macOS High Sierra

- contents of `terraform/ansible.cfg`:

  ```
    # If set, configures the path to the Vault password file as an 
    # alternative to specifying --vault-password-file on the command
    # line.
    vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt
    n
  ```

**Note**: when `project_directory/terraform/ansible.cfg` is commented out, ansible uses `~/.ansible.cfg` and is able to decrypt encrypted files.

###### EXPECTED RESULTS

I expect playbook to decrypt all encrypted vars using the ansible vault password saved in the path provide in the configuration file (ansible.cfg) provided in the project directory.

###### ACTUAL RESULTS

I get the error below:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* linode_linode.base: Error running command 'sleep 30; ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -u root --ask-pass -i '172.104.29.185,' ../ansible/provision.yml --extra-vars 'ip=000.111.22.185' -vvvv': exit status 5. Output: Error reading config file (/Users/pnotes/Code/Terraform/Test/terraform/ansible.cfg): File contains no section headers.
file: '/Users/pnotes/Code/Terraform/Test/terraform/ansible.cfg', line: 3
'vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt\n'
```

Can someone please explain why I keep getting the error **`exit status 5. Output: Error reading config file (/Users/pnotes/Code/Terraform/Test/terraform/ansible.cfg): File contains no section headers.`

- I also tried looking for info on how ansible generates the default `/etc/ansible.cfg` file but can't seem to track it down (I use python in a limited capacity so this might be why I am having a hard time with this)

Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ansible.cfg` is supposed to be divided into sections with headers of the form `[section_name]`.  The `vault_password_file` option, like the majority of the configuration options, belongs to the `[defaults]` section, so your `ansible.cfg` needs to look like:

```
[defaults]
vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Comment: ugh! I would have sworn (and lost) that I had that in there. I clearly needed sleep.

Comment: I had the same problem. I wonder why they did not include it into their reference documentation, see e.g. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html It only says that the file is in INI fromat.